# How to make the parameter of an Ocaml function be a mutable int?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I want to make a function in which the parameter is mutable.
I'm familiar with  `let a = ref 0` but how can i make "a" be a parameter for my function?

Comment: I recommend to not do such things. I consider this as bad programming style, especially in functional-programming.

Comment: Yes, you'll probably be better off returning the new value for `a`.

Answer (score 5):

If you ask Ocaml nicely, it will infer the right type for you:

```
 let incr x =  x:= !x + 1
```

> val incr : int ref -> unit = < fun >